# MS Graph API - System.MissingMethodException on startup - SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter..ctor

Tags: c#, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, swashbuckle

I am making an Azure functions app with Microsoft authentication. I want users of my app to be able to send an invite email to new users.

I am doing this using the Microsoft Graph API

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.6.0" />
```

and here is my call to the GraphServiceClient:

```
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authCodeCredential, scopes);
        var invitation = new Invitation
        {
            InvitedUserEmailAddress = "testuser@_____.com",
            InviteRedirectUrl = "https://mywebsite.com"
        };

        await graphClient.Invitations
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(invitation);
```

When I run this code, I get an exception on startup (not on the code that I changed):

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter..ctor(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)'.
  Source=AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle
  StackTrace:
   at AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle.SwashBuckleStartupExtension.AddSwashBuckle(IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly, Action`1 configureDocOptionsAction, IWebJobsBuilder webJobsBuilder)
   at AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle.SwashBuckleStartupExtension.AddSwashBuckle(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder, Assembly assembly, Action`1 configureDocOptionsAction)
   at api.Startup.Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) in D:\Github\inventive\________\webapp\api\api\Startup.cs:line 51
```

The exception happens on my call to builder.AddSwashBuckle:

```
        builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), opts =>
        {
            opts.SpecVersion = OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi2_0;
            opts.AddCodeParameter = true;
            opts.PrependOperationWithRoutePrefix = true;
            opts.Documents = new[]
            {
                new SwaggerDocument
                {
                    Name = "v1",
                    Title = "API",
                    Description = "The surface area for the API",
                    Version = "v2"
                }
            };
            opts.Title = "API";
            opts.XmlPath = "API.xml";
            opts.ConfigureSwaggerGen = (x =>
            {
                x.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc =>
                {
                    return apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo)
                        ? methodInfo.Name
                        : new Guid().ToString();
                });
            });
        });
```

When I am not referencing Microsoft.Graph, the app start up fine. I have tried moving my Microsoft.Graph reference to a new project, and referencing that project from the main project. But the same exception happens.

Do you have any suggestions for how I can resolve the startup exception?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you running?

Comment: What version of Azure functions are you using? You should consider using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide as Azure Functions v3 has some issues with managing dependencies of System.Text.Json